# Using react component in ant design table

Tags: antd

I want to add react components like antd Icon, Progressbar, Tag etc. to antd table

[image]

In the [online docs](https://ant.design/components/table/), there isn't any demo on this, is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There would be a LOT of demos if there was to be a demo of everything possible :-) !!!

Of course it is possible, you should look (in the docs you  linked to) at the `render` property of Table.Column. It allows you to return the cell content with any React Components, based on the table row/item which is provided in its arguments. The docs have weird names for the argument, I like to think of the render function as

`(cell, row, index) => { return (<any jsx>) }`

... where `cell` is the standard cell content if you hadn't provided a render function, `row` is the data you supplied to the table for this particular row, and `index`is the row index.